# Create Key Vault certificate using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I want to create a Key Vault and add secrets as well as certificates to it using an ARM template. I have been able to find a way of creating a Key Vault as well as adding secrets to it, but couldn't find any relevant solution of adding a new Self-signed certificate into Key Vault using just the ARM template.

Is this feature currently supported in ARM template ?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is currently not supported. You can only create secrets using ARM Templates.

Answer (score 1):

What i have done is:

Set up a endpoint that creates a random certificate for every request:
https://management.dotnetdevops.org/providers/DotNetDevOps.AzureTemplates/templates/KeyVault/certificates/demo/parameters?secretName=test&keyVaultName=test

It outputs the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "keyVaultName": {
      "value": "test"
    },
    "secretName": {
      "value": "test"
    },
    "secretValue": {
      "value": "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"
    },
    "certificateThumbprint": {
      "value": "AD99382EECC21A3456FFDD0B10FDB0399C53BF10"
    }
  }
}
```

this is deployed using a nested template

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "name": "CreateCertificate",
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[concat('https://management.dotnetdevops.org/providers/DotNetDevOps.AzureTemplates/templates/KeyVault/certificates/demo?secretName=test&keyVaultName=',reference('DeployKeyvault').outputs.keyVaultName.value)]",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parametersLink": {
                "uri": "[concat('https://management.dotnetdevops.org/providers/DotNetDevOps.AzureTemplates/templates/KeyVault/certificates/demo/parameters?secretName=test&keyVaultName=',reference('DeployKeyvault').outputs.keyVaultName.value)]",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    },
```

This works nice for this usecase.

Comment: Can you please further explain how you utilize this workaround when you want to reference the thumbprint value and use it as parameter for another resource which is dependent on the creation of the certificate?

Comment: i just put it in the output of the template

Comment: Not sure I have the complete picture. Can you please share a full example that shows how the experience requested above (reference certificate thumbprint) is answered? That’s much appreciated, as of now I first have to crest the vault, create the certificate and only then execute the template.

Comment: @johni I am a bit bussy this week. Lets try to follow up in the weekend about making a complete sample.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, this feature is currently not supported.

What you can do is create powershell script for importing certificates.
`Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate` will definitely help you with it.
Just run script after the deployment of Key Vault itself is finished and certificates will be imported.

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is currently not supported. You can only create secrets using ARM Templates.

You can use custom PowerShell script in the ARM template so that you can achieve whatever you are trying

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI**